# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar todos los elementos repetidos de una lista?

Tags: python, lista, if, bucle-for

Al hacer el bucle, hay un problema de rango y no lo logro identificar:

```
def eliminar_elementos(x):
    Control=len(x)
    y=int(input("Ingrese elemento a eliminar:"))
    for j in range(Control):
      if x[j]==y:
      remover=x[j]
      x.remove(remover)
```

Me da error de rango ya que al eliminar un elemento, la lista se achica. ¿Cómo lo deberia solucionar? ¿Reduciendo el rango?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar los duplicados "in place", sin crear una nueva lista, siguiendo tu idea original, la clave está en iterar la lista en orden inverso de forma que los índices restantes serán válidos en todo momento ya que siempre eliminamos elementos posteriores a ellos:

```
def eliminar_elementos(x):
    y = int(input("Ingrese elemento a eliminar:"))
    for j in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):
      if x[j] == y:
          del x[j]
```

---

> ```
> >>> l = [2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2]  
> >>> eliminar_elementos(l)
> Ingrese elemento a eliminar: 2
> >>> l
> [5, 3, 4]
> ```

La clave esta en  `range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1)`. El primer argumento (`start`) será el último índice de la lista, que es igual al numero de elementos de ésta menos uno (indexado base 0). El segundo es `-1`, ya que el último índice a generar es el 0 (primer elemento de la lista), hay que recordar que `range` no incluye el valor `stop` en el rango, por lo que no puede ser 0 ó iteraría solo hasta 1. El tercero (`step`) lógicamente ha de ser también -1 ya que  el rango se genera desde `len(x) - 1` hasta 0 restando 1 en cada paso.

`del` permite eliminar un elemento de la lista usando su índice, `list.remove` elimina la primera aparición del elemento pasado como argumento, se puede usar con este fin pero usando un `while`, no obstante es más ineficiente al necesitar iterar reiteradamente sobre la lista.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes filtrar usando *list comprehension*:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print("lista original", l)

y = int(input("Ingrese elemento a eliminar:"))

l_res = [x for x in l if x != y]

print("lista final", l_res)
```